# SetInterval and SetTimeout iterate array

Tags: javascript, loops, settimeout, setinterval

I want to make a simple iterate array with for. But can't make that script work... If anyone can give directions to self study, I appreciate any idea!

```js
    var colors = ['green', 'red', 'blue', 'grey', 'orange'];
    function chColor(){
    setInterval(
  function(colors){
     for(var i = 0; i <= colors.lenght; i++){
   document.body.style.backgroundColor = Colors[i];
  }},3000)}
    (function(){setTimeout(function(){chColor()},3000);})();
```

Comment: Do you call your chColor anywhere? Also you execute your full iteration every 3 seconds

Comment: what should happen after the last color? start at the beginning of the array again?

Comment: what is Colors[i] ? it should be `colors[i]`, notice the case.

Comment: and colors.length; instead of colors.lenght, (notice the typo)

Comment: and should be `i < colors.length`

Comment: why do you have taken a timeout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take an index for the colors and increment after every interval and adjust with remainder operator and length of the array.

Your issues:

- Interval with a function with an argument, this paramter is never handed over, so it is `undefined`.
- `for` loop in interval which iterates straight on and end at the end with a used
- array `Colors` which does not exist. Javascript is a case sensitive language.
- Because of the `for` loop, the final color, if the right array would be taken, is always the same.
- Unclear use of `setTimeout` which defers the call of `chColor` by 3 seconds. The first change of color is anther 3 seconds later ...

```js
function chColor(colors, i) {
    setInterval(
        function() {
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
            i++;
            i %= colors.length;
        },
        3000
    );
}

var colors = ['green', 'red', 'blue', 'grey', 'orange'];
chColor(colors, 0); // take colors as array and start with index zero
```

Comment: Really appreciate your answer, Nina Scholz! I'm self studying and making little experiments... But can't understand what my issue yet...

Answer (score 1):

Lot of corrections needed. Find inline comments below:

```js
var colors = ['green', 'red', 'blue', 'grey', 'orange'];
function chColor(){
  setInterval(
    function(){ // do not pass colors in the method here, global colors should be used. 
      for(var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++){ // i should be < colors.length, it's 0 indexed.
        console.log(colors[i])// should be colors[i] not Colors[i]
      }},1000)}
(function(){setTimeout(chColor,1000);})(); // don't really need to make a blank function and call chColor, passing the function name will do. it's a callback
```

Try and run the snippet.

PS: Shortened the time to 1s for this example.

**Edit**: If you want to change color between every n seconds:

```js
var colors = ['green', 'red', 'blue', 'grey', 'orange'];
function chColor(){
  var i = 0; 
  setInterval(function(){
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
    i = (i+1) % colors.length; // increment i and cycle through loop
  },1000)
}

(function(){setTimeout(chColor,1000);})();
```

Comment: Thanks for your improve, kiddorails! I made a lot of typos. I'm studying your code now.

Comment: `i = ++i ...` really?

Comment: @NinaScholz It was unintuitive, agreed. but was not an error, per se. :) Edited.